# How to re-enable button hovers in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/Snowfiring/pen/oKpBh

I'm attempting to disable the animation on click because when clicked, the animation starts moving and if your still hovered over an object it freezes, the end result is the animation stops running and it just moves,

my code to freeze the animation on hover is

```
function show_box() {
  if($(window).width() > 768) {
    $('.tab-content').hide(0,
      function() {
        $(this).prev().css('right', '29.337803855%');
        $(this).prev().children().children().click(function () {
            $('.favorite').off('mouseenter').css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'running');
            $('.secret').off('mouseenter').css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'running');
            $('.current-projects').off('mouseenter').css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'running');
            $('.tab-selection').animate({right: 0}, 3000).queue(function() {
                $('.tab-content').show(1000);
            });
            $('.favorite').on('mouseenter');
            $('.secret').on('mouseenter');
            $('.current-projects').on('mouseenter');
        });
      }
    );
  }    
}
```

to disable hover on mouseenter and mouseleave i used

```
.off('mouseenter')
```

but after the function is done, and the moving complete I set

```
.on('mouseenter')
```

but it doesn't re-enable.

Answer (score 0):

At first your code could be much shorter, i think.

And please take a look in the jQuery doc for the on function it does Not, what you are expecting!

I think you should set a global variable if it is disabled at the moment and in the eventhandler you firstly check the variable and abort if its disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on the coding being shorter i changed the function so its much shorter.

Comment: I've found setting an event handler for .mouseenter unless you move your mouse after click doesnt work. Where as this does